# How to parse table inside table?

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I have an html content, that look like this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>blabla</td>
<td>blabla</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>blabla</td>
<td>blabla</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>blabla</td>
<td><table>THIS IS MY TABLE CONTENT</table></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to parse the THIS IS MY TABLE CONTENT and ONLY this table, the outer table is irrelevant for me.
I'm using Simple HTML DOM parser and right now my code look like this:

```
$table = $html->find('table');

    foreach ($table->find('table') as $tbl){

        foreach ($tbl->find('tr') as $tr){

            foreach ($tr->find('td') as $td){
             // some logic
            }

        }

    }
```

My problem is, that this way I'm not getting any result. How can I perform this parsing the right way?

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

What about using DOM with `XPath`

```
$str = '<table><tbody><tr><td>blabla</td><td>blabla</td></tr><tr><td>blabla</td><td>blabla</td></tr><tr><td>blabla</td><td><table>THIS IS MY TABLE CONTENT</table></td></tr></tbody></table>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str); // $str is your html string
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$tables = $xpath->query('.//td/table'); // fetch all tables inside td
foreach($tables as $table){
   // Do your stuff with each table
   echo $table->nodeValue; // $table is your current $table
}
```

Comment: I want to use Simple HTML DOM. I will have a look if I can use XPath with it, thanks.

Comment: EDIT: I tried this Xpath with Simple HTML Dom and it returns the values 3 times...

Answer (score 0):

The inner table would be:

```
$html->find('table table', 0);
```